# What does this mean? "Your UK visa application has been issued"

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, europe

> Your UK visa application has been issued.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT GO TO THE VISA APPLICATION CENTRE BEFORE THEY CONTACT YOU.
>
> You will be contacted by the Visa Application Centre when your documents are ready for collection, or have been dispatched via courier where this is relevant.
>
> You are reminded that you should avoid making travel plans until you have collected your passport, as the outcome of your visa application is not final until you receive your passport.
>
> Please ensure you check the details on your visa when collecting your passport. If you need to contact us you can do so via our International Enquiry Service at www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk
>
> Kind regards,
>
> UK Visas and Immigration
>   British Embassy Abu Dhabi

---

***Your UK visa application has been issued.***

I know words like processed, forwarded, received, refused but never heard anything like that, so I am confused.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: There is no hidden meaning to these emails. It says nothing about the success of your application if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: @DJClayworth This part ''Your UK visa application has been issued'' i know words like processed forwarded received refused but never heard anything like that so i am confused

Comment: To 'issue' something is to 'to produce or provide something official'. (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issue see the 'verb' definition)

Comment: In this case, I actually think the word *issue* may have been used by mistake: more often the statement says something like *assessed and a decision has been made* or... *and a visa has been issued.* Either way, @AyaanMustafa, you'll have to wait until you get your passport.

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry. I'm a native speaker and I still have no clue what "Your visa application has been issued" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't know what it means either. I know what it means to issue a visa or issue a decision, but I don't know what issuing an application is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: @Ayaan Mustafa On another forun i have seen people getting visa after this statement you are reffering to in the email.Kindly uodate us when you get passport back. It think it is their new way to say you got an approval.

Comment: @Ayaan Mustafa I also got the same email. Have you got passport back and what is the decision ?

Comment: @DJClayworth:  What part of the question don't you understand?

Comment: @AyaanMustafa  You were correct in thinking that the text makes **no sense**.   Whoever wrote it, was an idiot  :)  Fortunately it looks like SgrA below is familiar with the process and knows what the message represents.  Cheers.

Comment: @Warda123 since they say "the outcome of your visa application is not final until you receive your passport," I strongly suspect that they mean that a decision has been made but they cannot say whether the decision was to grant or refuse the visa.  To conclude that this message means the visa is to be granted, we need evidence that unsuccessful applicants do not receive this message.  There does not seem to be any such evidence.

Comment: @DJClayworth "To 'issue' something is to 'to produce or provide something official'": but an application is produced by an official body only in its blank form.  To say that the visa office has issued an application after the applicant has submitted it is just confusing.

Comment: I got the similar email and my application was success so I believe this email with keyword "Issued" actually means that visa has been issued

Comment: Hi @AyaanMustafa, would you please tell me if you got your visa or not?

Answer (score 12):

It means that the British Embassy in Abu Dhabi has processed your application and dispatched it to the Visa Application Centre (VAC) where you submitted your passport. Once the VAC has received your passport, they will contact you about collecting it (or courier it to you, if you have availed this service). They have reminded you not to make any travel plans because they don't advise the outcome of your application by email: you will have to open the sealed envelope to ascertain if your application was successful.

Comment: and also because it may take some time for the documents to arrive and they can't know in advance how long that will be.